Serverless Framework Packaging Includes node_modules
I'm using serverless framework to deploy lambdas in AWS. While deploying I'm getting the node_modules too attached with my handler. Though i excluded the node_modules folder in my serverless.yml file.
I followed this serverless Documentation .
Here is the part of my serverless.yml file.I'm using serverless V4.3.3
package:
  individually:  true
  patterns:
    - '!node_modules/**'

functions:
  generateToken:
    handler: generateToken/index.generateToken
    memorySize: 256
    timeout: 10 
    package:
      patterns:
        -'!node_modules/**'
        - generateToken/**

I tried with
exclude and include option too, Like this
 package:
   exclude:
     - 'node_modules/**'
   include:
     - generateToken/**
 

But Still every time i gets the node_modules in the serverless build package so on in lambda console too.

You’re deploying code written in JavaScript? Which probably uses packages you installed? Then you do need those node_modules dependencies…!?

@deceze I already included required dependencies as an layer. I don't need to package these with my function handlers.


Have you considered using the package option at the function level?
Have you tried using it without an individually flag?
As per docs, it says "Directories and files to include in the deployed package". Perhaps try including everything that you need. This might work.
Try removing single quotes in '!node_modules/**'

    # Packaging rules specific to this function
    package:
      # Directories and files to include in the deployed package
      patterns:
        - src/**
        - handler.js
        - '!.git/**'
        - '!.travis.yml'

